Parsing 12 byte buffer into two u64
I have a performance critical inner loop that must parse small buffers into integers. I was wondering what the most efficient way of doing it. As I need Little-Endian numbers, most CPUs can accomplish these through single loads followed by masking out some bytes. The functions are the following and I was wondering how to most efficiently implement them in Rust:
#[inline(always)]
fn unpack16(x: u64, y: u64) -> [u8; 16] {
    let x = x.to_le_bytes();
    let y = y.to_le_bytes();

    [
        x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7],
        y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6], y[7]
    ]
}

#[inline(always)]
fn pack16(b: [u8; 16]) -> (u64, u64) {
    let x = u64::from_le_bytes([b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7]]);
    let y = u64::from_le_bytes([b[8], b[9], b[10], b[11], b[12], b[13], b[14], b[15]]);

    (x, y)
}

#[inline(always)]
fn unpack12(x: u64, y: u64) -> [u8; 12] {
    let x = x.to_le_bytes();
    let y = y.to_le_bytes();

    [
        x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5],
        y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5],
    ]
}

#[inline(always)]
fn pack12(b: [u8; 12]) -> (u64, u64) {
    let x = u64::from_le_bytes([b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], 0, 0]);
    let y = u64::from_le_bytes([b[6], b[7], b[8], b[9], b[10], b[11], 0, 0]);

    (x, y)
}

I could always take the raw address of the right position of the arrays and through unsafe code load the an u64 from that address. However, it would seem that there must be better ways of doing that than resorting to unsafe.
EDIT: After playing around quite a bit in Compiler Explorer, I noticed that this implementation of unpack generates the same assembly that I would have written by hand:
fn unpack12(x: u64, y: u64) -> [u8; 12] {
    let combined = (x as u128) | ((y as u128) << 48);
    combined.to_le_bytes()[..12].try_into().unwrap()
}


After checking with the playground (See top left > Show assembly), it seems your unpack_* functions optimize pretty badly for some reason. Using copy_from_slice seems to improve the situation a lot. As for pack, you could also use copy_from_slice to simplify it, but it doesn't look like it'll improve performance.

Weirdly, I could not get LLVM to emit a full store (instead of two half and quarter stores) for x (it always swaps the stores for x and y, which makes it unable to emit a full store) by any means, other than using inline assembly. https://godbolt.org/z/a1W4rc4sn. Benchmarked, this inline assembly is the fastest version for unpacking (1.2841ns, vs. 1.3788ns for copy_from_slice() and 2.0316ns for your method).

Your method of using u128 has ~roughly equivalent performance to the inline assembly.

Since you're doing this in a loop, you might consider SIMD, especially if you're storing the u64 results to contiguous memory.  (If you're using them for something within the same loop that parses them, getting them back into GPRs from a SIMD vector would probably be worse than two overlapping 8-byte loads from the 12-byte buffer, and a right-shift for one, AND for the other.)

Assuming you can safely load 16 bytes from your 12-byte buffer, on x86-64 this would be movdqu / pshufb to put the bytes where you want and introduce zeros in the right places.  With AVX2, you could do it for 4 u64 at once, doing a 32-byte load from the middle of four 6-byte elements, so the low and high 128-bit lanes each have the bytes for two integers, so vpshufb (with different indices in high and low lanes) could work.

So anyway, this is such a tiny task that it matters a lot how you're using the results.  This function needs to inline into the loop its called in, so args in registers for a stand-alone function is maybe unrealistic depending on where they come from.  If data's coming from memory, partial-register shenanigans like an 8-byte load then mov ax, [mem] to merge a new low 2 bytes into RAX might be useful, leaving 4 bytes left to copy...
